# Linux Level Interrupts - When registering with existing interrupt, handler doesn't get called

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I have a level HIGH interrupt hardware device and have a working interrupt handler in linux using register_irq();

The problem is, if I register the IRQ while the device has already raised the level high interrupt, the handler doesn't get called.

If I have the device then lower the interrupt, and re-raise it, then my handler will get called.

This seems like a bug to me, that you can only get an interrupt for level interrupts if you register before the hardware moves the line high.

Can anyone confirm this is normal behavor and if not, how to fix it?